# using namespace just for initialiser list

Tags: c++, list, namespaces, using

I have a lot of namespace usage in an initialiser list and would like a *using namespace* to reduce the verbosity. However the initialiser list is outside the scope of the constructor braces so I would have to place the *using* outside the constructor and pollute the rest of the file with it. Is there a way to scope the using as I want? Rather than:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
    m_one(nsConstants::ONE),
    m_two(nsConstants::TWO),
    m_three(nsConstants::THREE)
{}
```

I want:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
    using namespace nsConstants;
    m_one(ONE),
    m_two(TWO),
    m_three(THREE)
{}
```

_

Comment: What language is it? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Sorry Tomasz, and thanks for the comment. Edited to add C++ tag.

Comment: To avoid confusion should call it "ctor-initializer" since the C++ grammar element "initializer-list" is something else (the part between `{}` for aggregate initializers). And what is so bad in "polluting" the rest of the file with the using? It is your .cxx file, not a header so it should be ok. Another option would be to do `using nsConstants::ONE;`, but what you want is not possible.

Comment: Hi PlasmaHH, I'm a programmer not a compiler writer so I prefer to use  language in the scope of the user such as in the C++ FAQ. I think I'll be more accurate that way. The pollution is not ok in my case because I'm using the namespaces to prevent name clashes. Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The standard offers some less good alternatives:

```
// The stuff you want to use.
namespace foo { namespace bar {
    class Frob {};
} }
```

Now, from ***least polluting to most polluting***.

`typedef` makes it possible to write that alias in a `private` section of your class definition:

```
// I)
class Schwarzschild {
          typedef foo::bar::Frob FbFrob;
public:   Schwarzschild () : a(FbFrob()), b(FbFrob()) {}
private:  FbFrob a,b,c;
};
```

But you can also use it unit-globally, but with an opportunity to rename it:

```
// II)
class Schwarzschild {
public:   Schwarzschild ();
private:  foo::bar::Frob a,b,c;
};

// cxx-file
typedef foo::bar::Frob FbFrob; 
Scharzschild::Scharzschild() : a(FbFrob()) {}
```

You can also alias namespaces:

```
// III)
namespace fb = foo::bar;
class Planck {
public:   Planck () : a(fb::Frob()), b(fb::Frob()) {}
private:  fb::Frob a,b,c;
};
```

Or you can cherry pick symbols from other namespaces, with the disadvantage that your `Frob` may collide with another `Frob` in your unit of translation:

```
//  IV)
using foo::bar::Frob;
class Mach {
public:   Mach () : a(Frob()), b(Frob()) {}
private:  Frob a,b,c;
};
```

Just for the sake of completeness, the most polluting solution is `using namespace`.

```
//  V)
using namespace foo::bar;
class Newton {
public:   Newton () : a(Frob()), b(Frob()) {}
private:  Frob a,b,c;
};
```

Note that III, IV and V can also be limited to your cxx-file, like in the Schwarzschild-example.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer phresnel, I have a lot of types in the namespace which would mean a lot of additional code in I, II and IV. III shortens the namespace but in my case it is already short and V is the one I want to avoid. So in this case I'll stick to my original code.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly not possible. There exists no such thing like a "local using" in C++.  So you'll have to stick to the scope operator or use `using`.

Comment: >> no such thing like a "local using" in C++. 
Well I meant like:

    void myFunction()
    {
        using namespace nsConstants;
        i = ONE;
    }

which is in C++. See many other entries on stackoverflow for details. (Sorry, I can't format this as code.)